# If the multiverse theory is true, can there be a Universe where there are different laws of physics?

Tags: cosmology, multiverse

This is probably a very difficult question. But my question is essentially this, if there are other Universes can different laws of physics exist in those Universes and if so, can't there be a Universe where the laws of physics are so different that the multiverse theory has to come out as false?

Comment: different physics constant (say, speed of light)? or sth like linearity $\rightarrow$ non-linearity?

Comment: Slightly different laws of physics in the local universes of any multiverse are what Smolin assumes in the intro to his 2013 pop-sci "Time Reborn", but the possibility that such laws might lead to a denial of the multiverse's existence is certainly an interesting one, as it would further the insulation of the local universes from each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a "metaverse" in which there are possibly an infinity of independent "Universes", then logically, the existence of any individual "Universe" is contingent on the existence of the "metaverse" rather than the other way around.

That is to say, the laws of any "Universe" must logically be compatible with the existence of "the metaverse" that, in fact, makes the "Universe" possible.

Otherwise... well?

Comment: Any theory or speculation saying that the laws of the Metaverse allow/disallow/can allow different laws of physics among different universes?

Answer (score 2):

this is of course, entirely philosophical, and cannot be answered from physics considerations. But it is a fair question nonetheless, so i'll take a shot.

The only notion of metaverse that makes sense to me is [Tegmark's vision of mathematically consistent universes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis). This merges with the anthropic principle in order to state that universes have few constraints on their laws, which is that they are Gödel-complete, and that they allow sentient beings to develop that can do interesting questions about existence as we are just doing here. Any mathematical set of evolution rules that can give rise to life, will have solutions where intelligent entities that do those questions.

Unless some fundamental reason make the laws of our universe 'special' in a way that makes it unique regarding it's ability to host intelligent life, most probably, there is a huge family, probably infinite, of set of physical laws that can host intelligent life.

Even in the specific case of string theory universes, there might be a lot of different vacuums that can host life. This is still a daunting technical problem to analyse, but at least is approachable in principle.

Answer (score 0):

> If the multiverse theory is true, can there be a universe with different laws of physics.

Yes, of course. This follows trivially from the way that you phrased the question ie as a syllogism.

*However*, the 'if' is a very big if. The multiverse hypothesis is highly speculative, not very well understood, and has absolutely **no** evidence that substantiates it. It is essentially a figment of the physicists imagination and has been hyped endlessly. There are many more interesting things in physics than the multiverse hypothesis.

Philosophically speaking, it makes no sense to think that there can be differing physical laws; simply because one can then ask for the law that regulates these differing laws.

So the answer is: **No, there isn't**

Answer (score -2):

If u mind the MWI interpretation of QM, then the answer is: there are no universes where 1st law ofb thermodynamics does not work, but there are universes where the 2nd law of thermodynamics does not work. So some laws work everywhere while others do not.

Comment: I don't think the MWI actually says that. Could you expand on the reasons for this or otherwise give a reference? (Also, note that this is an old question with an accepted answer, there is no need to play necromancer unless you have got something really substantial to say)